# Understanding Apache rules in <Directory> directive

Tags: apache-2.2, security, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I have tried reading the manual although to be honest I am still finding it hard to understand and get my head around what the Order/Allow actually does.

I have the following code inside a virtual host, I'm not clear what this code inside the `<directory> .....</directory>`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin digital@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.com-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

could somebody try to explain row by row in an easier way?
I have had security problems with an older server that was using this conf code, and I would make the new server more secure. In this server I have a lot of wordpress websites so I have to use the .htaccess.

Answer (score 6):

## Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

**Indexes**: if you try to access a directory that doesn't have a DirectoryIndex, such as `index.php`, the content of the directory will be shown.

**FollowSymLinks**: allows apache to use symbolic links. This can improve the perfomance but can be a security issue too.

**MultiViews**: not sure about it but, from googling a bit it looks like a security risk. [Some info](https://www.systemcodegeeks.com/web-servers/apache/apache-multiviews-mod_rewrite/)

## AllowOverride All

Allow `.htaccess` files to override every configuration parameter set in `apache2.conf`

## Order allow,deny

By default, access to a directory is forbidden.

## Allow from all

Allow connections from any network.

Comment: thanks, much clear now.
If I don't want to Indexes the folder what is the value that I have to write?

my conf has some great security problem or is it ok like this?

Comment: You'd need to change it to `-Indexes`. Also, I was googling about `MultiViews` option as I didn't know what it was and out of four recommendations, two of them where "attack" and "exploit", so I guess you can have a problem there.

Comment: MultiViews is dangerous because it allows file suffixes to be anywhere in the filename. Makes it hard to predict what an uploaded file can do.